# networking options for a docker image in minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I have a docker image (usermanagement:latest) from which I normally create containers this way when I'm testing locally:

```
docker run --net "host" -p 8096:8096 -v $(pwd):/etc  usermanagement:latest -port 8096 -configfile /etc/config
```

Both `port` and `configfile` has default values and port's default value is 8096.

I can then simply reach it at `localhost:8096/1/users/some_api`. This gives me the flexibility of being able to create many containers of the same image listening to different ports.

Now, I've pushed this image into a private registry and want to use minikube which also has access to the registry (all good and fine).

**Problem is** I can't figure out how to specify networking options (`--net` or `-p`) or even volume option (`-v`) when creating a Kubernetes deployment.

I tried:

```
kubectl run usr --image=$REGISTRY_IP:80/usermanagement:latest --port=8096
kubectl expose deployment usr --target-port=8096 --type=NodePort
```

Where REGISTRY_IP is the IP of the private registry from which the image has already been pulled into the minikube's docker.

I've verified the service is created and exposed, but I can't reach (getting 404) the container in minikube using:

```
curl -v http://192.168.42.149:31900/1/users/some_api
```

Service's IP and port above came from:

```
kubectl get svc usr
minikube ip
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I advise you to run `kubectl logs` so you can check the if there's any kind of startup error. Also, you can use `kubectl exec` to enter the container and see if the endpoint is available.

Comment: well, I managed to solve this problem by creating Yaml files and then `kubectl create -f yaml_file`